# Unrepairable error in disk structure in Onyx

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, filesystem, error

I've run [Onyx 3.1.7](http://www.titanium.free.fr) and received the following disk structure error:

```
Error: -69845: File system verify or repair failed
Underlying error: 8: POSIX reports: Exec format error

The disk needs to be repaired.
```

I've rebooted system in recovery mode and attempted to run the *First Aid* with use of the Disk Utility, however, after rebooting and running *Onyx* again I've arrived at the same error. The System is running on [el-capitan](/questions/tagged/el-capitan) with 500GB flash storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried booting into single user mode (hold down <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> at startup) then at the prompt executing the command `fsck -fy` until no errors appear? When you're done, type `reboot` at the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

When you get a filesystem error, the escalation steps are the same in just about all cases:

1. Make a backup and/or verify your backup is sufficient
2. Boot to another OS (Recovery HD, utility tool, internet recovery, external drive) and run Disk Utility or whatever tool to repair.
3. Erase the volume and set it up again.
4. Test the erased volume - if it passes, reinstall the OS and restore backup. If it fails, repair the hardware.

Comment: While option 3 is the cheapest way to go about it you could also use a third-party disk repair tool at this point. Diskwarrior will often fix errors that the OS can't fix with the built-in tools. Though no guarantee, sometimes even third-party tools won't fix the issue then you either reformat and restore or replace the drive.